# Can I generate and show two table of contents with reftex simultaneously?

Tags: latex, reftex-mode

I work in a main tex-document, where I use reftex to display the table of contents. But I also have another buffer where I want to show a toc.

Is this possible?

Now the `*toc*`-buffer is overtaken by any tex buffer in which I use `reftex-toc`.

Comment: I don't think so, but I can see how that might be useful. You can use `outline-minor-mode` in LaTeX buffers, which lets you toggle the display of sections via `outline-toggle-children`. Not what you're looking for, but it does provide a compact view of your document that's sort of like a TOC.